# Python - Silent install & validation of software

Tags: python, validation, automation, installation

I've written a Python 2.7.2 script (for Windows 7) that installs software applications automatically, here's a sample of how I'm doing this:

```
import subprocess

WinZip = '//fileServer/Applications/Winzip/winzip9full/setup.exe'
install_WinZip = subprocess.Popen(WinZip)
```

Right now, this opens the GUI installer for WinZip and makes the user go through all the steps. Is there a way I can automatically install it without user input?

Additionally, is there a way I can validate if such an installation was successful?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the responses, I'll mark an answer when my boss decides if we home-brew the solution or use an existing software package.

Answer (score 1):

Not from Python, no (except with a lot of effort). If you want to install software automatically, you should probably use the sort of server management software designed to do those kinds of things.

I haven't worked with software like that since 1995, so I don't know what is good, but here is one that's open source:

http://wpkg.org/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems like a good alternative to writing installation automation scripts in Python, however not sure if my boss wants a home-brewed solution (programmed by us) or if he'd be fine with using WPKG or similar solutions that already exist. Thanks again.

Comment: @Murkantilism: This is a problem solved twenty years ago. He should want the solution that already exists. It's going to work better. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the software is packaged as an MSI, you can use silent install (also called unattended install) to avoid displaying the UI. But a setup.exe may not have that option. You should check what is the software used to create the setup.exe, and check if they have command line installation option. Installer created by installshield *may* have them.

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q101901

After that, it's just a question of sending the correct command line parameters to the installer.

Comment: Unfortunately, only 2 of the software packages I need to auto-install are MSI, the rest are setup.exe files. I'll look into command line installation options, thanks very much for the reply.